# What is the maximum supported height of an html image?

Tags: html

I have an image which gets stretched to `75069px` and just noticed that somewhere about `65536px` the image stops showing up. It is hard to tell because where it ends seems to have undefined behavior.

Is there a maximum to an `<img>` tag's height?

Comment: Why would you want to have an image higher than any viewport?

Comment: @jtheman - It provides a very visually appealing gradient. Lightweight, doesn't lag or slow down the browser because the original image is small.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and guess that yes, it's 2^16 (2 bytes), 65536px

Comment: You could probably achieve the same gradient effect with CSS3

Comment: @jtheman - CSS3 provides gradients, although not for use in older browsers (ie8 or 9 for example). Also, this gradient is non repeating, unique, and non uniform.

Comment: There are many polyfills out there to cover for browser inconsistencies. Modernizr fixes most CSS3 behaviours in IE. But as you have said i havent seen your image. But why cant you make several images 65536px high and add them after one another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG format supports a maximum image size of 65535×65535.

Source: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#section_13

Comment: In fact, this was using a gif (which is also under the same constraints). Oddly enough, the issue only arises when using firefox. Both chrome and ie have no issue stretching the image the full 75k. Changing the format to `png` (which supposedly supports up to 2^31) did not solve the problem either. I think this could still be the reason so I will leave the answer as accepted.